# standalone click-to-run office 2016 with msi publisher 2016

Tags: windows-7, installation, microsoft-office, microsoft-office-2016, microsoft-publisher

I have a windows 7 PC.

I have a valid Office 2016 Home and Business licence.

I have a valid Publisher 2016 licence.

Office 2016 is installing with Click-To-run, Publisher is installing via MSI.

I want to change one to the other as I am getting a compatibility error. I don't care which way I go.

Error when Office is installed first:
[image: Error when Office is installed first]

Error when Publisher is installed first:
[image: Error when Publisher is installed first]

I can't find any download links that don't ask me for more money or require me to switch to office 365. What is the best way to resolve the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the Microsoft's answer (from a call to answer desk):

You cannot install an Office pack (Home & Student, Home & Buisness, Pro Plus...) 2013+ with a standalone install of an Office product (Publisher in your case)

Microsoft's solution : Uninstall your office suite > install Publisher > use Publisher > uninstall Publisher > reinstall Office suite > use Office suite!

Microsoft's 2nd solution : Use a second computer

Microsoft's 3rd solution : Buy an Office 365 pack with Publisher on it (Of course, and I can put my previous licenses in the trashcan! No problem)

To sum up : You CANNOT install an Office Pack WITH Publisher

Have a nice day :)